# What is the center and radius of convergence of this complex series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2-i}{1+5i}) z^n$$

So my book says the center = 0 and the radius $= \sqrt{\frac{26}{5}}$

I don't know how we go there.

So I can see how the above can be written: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2-i}{1+5i}) (z - 0)^n$$

and that $a = \frac{2-i}{1+5i}$ and that $a_{n+1} = \frac{2-i}{1+5i}$ too so by Cauchy Hadamard doesn't that mean: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{2-i}{1 + 5i} \cdot \frac{1 + 5i}{2-i}\right | = 1 = R$ so where does the $\sqrt{\frac{26}{5}}$ come from?

Comment: As written the radius is indeed equal to $1$: the coefficient of $z^n$ being constant. Is there not a typo whoever?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2-i}{1+5i} z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (kz)^n \to r=\frac 1{|k|}\\but\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2-i}{1+5i}) z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} kz^n \to r= \frac11$$

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define $x_n={2-i\over 1+5i}$ and apply the ratio test since you have obviously ignored $z^n$. Try to apply the ratio test over the full summand of the $\sum$ operator, i.e. $x_n=({2-i\over 1+5i})z^n$ to obtain what you wish for.

Comment: I'm applying Cauchy's Hadamard for the radius of convergence